# SK test in lmeR model: Error in XXlist[[ii]] <- XX : attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to perform a scot knot test in a lmer model, I want the Prov means ranking!
what should I put in which=??

```
lmer1 <- with(inDB, lmer(stVOL8 ~ Rep + (1|Prov), data=inDB))
sk2 <-  SK(lmer1, which='Prov')
summary(sk2)

Error in XXlist[[ii]] <- XX : attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

Running the code to rank the Rep worked!

```
lmer1 <- with(inDB, lmer(stVOL8 ~ Rep + (1|Prov), data=inDB))
sk2 <-  SK(lmer1, which='Rep')
summary(sk2)

Goups of means at sig.level = 0.05 
  Means G1
9 99.91  a
5 99.88  a
8 99.86  a
4 99.85  a
2 99.84  a
1 99.82  a
3 99.72  a
7 99.61  a
6 99.42  a
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're using `SK()` from the [ScottKnott package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ScottKnott/index.html).

Your problem is that you are trying to run the test on a *random effect* component of the model. One of the fundamental limitations of the mixed-model framework is that it's impossible to make inferences on differences among levels of a random effect; you can test hypotheses about the *distribution* of effects (e.g., test a null hypothesis that the variance of the RE is zero), but you can't test hypotheses about differences in effects among levels of the grouping variable.

For more help in achieving your goal you might need to ask a question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).